# How to pass foreign key for creating table in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Here is my two tables , I want to pass my guest_id as a foreign key inside reservation table . but it's given error..

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE MyGuests (
    guest_id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(50),
    reg_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    )";

// // sql to create table

$sql = "CREATE TABLE reservation (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
FOREIGN KEY(guest_id) REFERENCES MyGuests(guest_id),
room INT(11) NOT NULL,
price FLOAT(11) NOT NULL,
reg_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)";
```

where is the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

You need also add the column guest_id  to your table reservation

Like:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE MyGuests (
    guest_id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(50),
    reg_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    )";

// // sql to create table

$sql = "CREATE TABLE reservation (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
guest_id INT(6) UNSIGNED,
room INT(11) NOT NULL,
price FLOAT(11) NOT NULL,
reg_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
FOREIGN KEY(guest_id) REFERENCES MyGuests(guest_id)
)";
```

Comment: How to  insert data into reservation

Comment: ? You save the userid in a session variable or you put in into a hidden POST or GET variable, the usual way

Comment: POST : find out the name of guests whose room cost is more than 4000 Tk BD.